# Display: Grid problems with A size

Tags: html, css

My problem is simple, I have buttons which are simple `<h1>` and i want them to link me to the other pages with `<a>`. Simple as that, but when I use

```
<a href="#"><h1>Index</h1></a>
```

I get a problem where the a tag takes much more space than i would like it to.
Here is the code for the classes header and buttons

```
.header{display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr; text-align: center; grid-gap: 20vw; } 
.buttons{display: grid; grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 0.8fr 0.8fr 0.8fr; grid-gap: 3.33%;}
```

And here is how the HTML file looks:

```
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div>
                <img src="assets/MMLogo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="index.html"><h1>Index</h1></a>
                <h1>Clients</h1>
                <h1>About Us</h1>
                <h1>Offices</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Browser Inspection on h1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFObx.png)
[Browser Inspection on a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49tbh.png)

So my question is: how do I make the a's size to be the same as the h1's size?
Any improvements to the code are welcomed too!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You mean like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QmexrO

Comment: I mean that I want the `<a>` to be at the same place as the `<h1>` and to have the same size

Comment: I think you need to explain more...it's *really* not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, please provide some more clear context. The only solution I can come up with taking the info provided into consideration is to either nest your link in the <h1> tag or set a size that you're happy with using CSS..